# Bash split dataset into 1 line per pair

Tags: string, bash, loops

First of all sorry if the title isn't the clearest, wasn't really sure how to express the issue better.

Essentially I receive data into a bash script(I have no control over the format of said data) that arrives in the following format :

```
(Name: Foo bar; UUID: <blah-blah-0101>; AnotherField: Some text; TieredField: (Number: 123; Text: More Text; YetAnotherTier: (Name: somename; IP: 125.214.21.4) ; ) ; NumericalData: 4; MoreInfo: Some Information) ;
```

Now what I want to do is loop through each Key/Value pair so that I can process the information. Obviously removing the leading/trailing "() ;" is straightforward. Then I figured maybe replaceing ";" with newlines, but that breaks because of the different tiers.

In regards to tiers, I am not concerned with looping inside them, I am only concerned with the highest level so as to speak. Thus :

```
TieredField: (Number: 123; Text: More Text; YetAnotherTier: (Name: somename; IP: 125.214.21.4) ; )
```

Is one simple pair as far as I am concerned.

Expected outcome :

```
Name: Foo bar
UUID: 
AnotherField: Some text
TieredField: (Number: 123; Text: More Text; YetAnotherTier: (Name: somename; IP: 125.214.21.4) ; )
NumericalData: 4
MoreInfo: Some Information
```

Since I am familiar with looping through lines of a text block, converting the original string to the above outcome would be sufficient, although an answer that directly loops through each of the above lines would also work.

Not really sure how to approach this, so any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: How about a parser generator? There are plenty, for example http://www.antlr.org/. The "Quick Start; Sample" looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script that

- read the original one-line input file (input.txt)
- produces an output file (output.txt)

More:

- initially removes the outer two braces
- uses a counter to count the inner braces
- changing the IFS to read all characters (including whitespaces)

---

```
#!/bin/bash

WITHOUT_OUTER="`cat input.txt | cut -d"(" -f2- | rev | cut -d")" -f2- | rev`;"
PAIR=''
CNT=0
NEWLINE=0
OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=''
while read -n1 C
do
  if [ "$C" == '(' ]
  then
    CNT=$((CNT+1))
  elif [ "$C" == ')' ]
  then
    CNT=$((CNT-1))
  fi
  if [ $CNT -eq 0 ]
  then
    if [ "$C" == ';' ]
    then
      PAIR="$PAIR\n"
      NEWLINE=1
    fi
  elif [ "$C" == ';' ]
  then
    PAIR="$PAIR$C"
  fi
  if [ "$C" != ";" ]
  then
    if [ ! $NEWLINE -eq 1 ]
    then
      PAIR="$PAIR$C"
    else
      NEWLINE=0
    fi
  fi
done < <(echo $WITHOUT_OUTER)
echo -e "$PAIR" > output.txt
```

The formatted values are in output.txt then. `cat output.txt` will show you the result:

```
Name: Foo bar
UUID: <blah-blah-0101>
AnotherField: Some text
TieredField: (Number: 123; Text: More Text; YetAnotherTier: (Name: somename; IP: 125.214.21.4) ; )
NumericalData: 4
MoreInfo: Some Information
```

Answer (score 2):

It works:

```
# strip stdin up until first '(' is read
cut -d '(' -f2- | while read -r -n1 c; do
        case $c in
        ')') break; ;;
        # if read any char, this is field name, just print it
        [a-zA-Z]) echo -n "$c"; ;;
        # doublescore separates names from values
        :)
                echo -n ': '
                l=0
                while read -n1 c; do
                        case "$c" in
                        # we need to count levels of '(' ')'
                        '(') ((l++)); echo -n '('; ;;
                        ')') ((l--)); 
                             # if level gets under zero, break from here, look at `MoreInfo:` case
                             if ((l<0)); then 
                                 echo; break; 
                             else 
                                 echo -n ')'; 
                                 if ((l==0)); then 
                                     echo; break; 
                                 fi;
                             fi;
                             ;;
                        # ';' separetes the next field, but only if level is zero, cause otherwise those are nested fields
                        ';') 
                                if ((l==0)); then 
                                        echo; 
                                        break;
                                else 
                                        echo -n "$c"; 
                                fi;
                                ;;
                        *) echo -n "$c"; ;;
                        esac
                done;
                # if level is lower then zero, braek, look at `MoreInfo:` case
                if ((l<0)); then break; fi;
                ;;
        " ") ;;
        esac
done; 
cat >/dev/null
```

For the following input:

```
(Name: Foo bar; UUID: <blah-blah-0101>; AnotherField: Some text; TieredField: (Number: 123; Text: More Text; YetAnotherTier: (Name: somename; IP: 125.214.21.4) ; ) ; NumericalData: 4; MoreInfo: Some Information) ;
```

It produces the output:

```
Name: Foobar
UUID: <blah-blah-0101>
AnotherField: Sometext
TieredField: (Number:123;Text:MoreText;YetAnotherTier:(Name:somename;IP:125.214.21.4);)
NumericalData: 4
MoreInfo: SomeInformation
```

Comment: Works pretty well, except that spaces are stripped out.

Answer (score 0):

This is horribly inefficient, but it will work - this loop looks for the first '(' and the last ')' before printing anything between them as one string (also I assume the character '_' is not used...):

```
t=''
n=0
oIFS=$IFS
IFS=';'
for f in $(sed -e 's/^(//' -e 's/) ;$//')
do
    if [[ $f = *'('* ]]; then
        t="${t}_ $f"
        let n++
    elif [[ $f = *')'* ]]; then
        t="${t}_ $f"
        let n--
        [[ $n -eq '0' ]] && echo ${t##_  }
    elif [[ $n -ne '0' ]]; then
        t="${t}_ $f"
    else
        echo ${f## }
    fi

done | IFS=$oIFS sed 's/_/;/g'
```

The output is:

```
Name: Foo bar
UUID: <blah-blah-0101>
AnotherField: Some text
TieredField: (Number: 123;  Text: More Text;  YetAnotherTier: (Name: somename;  IP: 125.214.21.4) ;  )
NumericalData: 4
MoreInfo: Some Information
```

Comment: Oops, just saw @Kamil's answer, which is pretty much identical. Anyway the use of parsers, as suggested by the comments above, is highly advised.